# Changing webkit transition duration with javascript

Tags: php, webkit

I have a ticker-tape run of text but I would like to change the duration of the duration depending on the amount of text to be shown. When the amount is small, the text runs slowly which is fine but with a lot of text, the tape whizzes by.

```
.marquee {
    /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
    width: 800px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    background: GhostWhite;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}



/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
 }
```

In the html, I am running the span as follows:

```
 <p class="marquee"><span><?php echo getEvents(); ?></span></p>
```

getEvents() is a php function that populates the ticker; from this I'd like to determine the length of text to throttle the speed of the text

Comment: Can you also include what you have tried in getEvents() so far? Would make it easier for ppl to make suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `20s` in `animation` directive that says how much time the text has to move across its container.  Short text will move slowly to cover the distance in 20 seconds.  Much longer text will have to move much faster.

See this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s40e3Lng/2/

The following JS/jquery sets the `time` to cross the `<p>` to a formula based on `len`gth of of the string inside the .

```
$('p.marquee span').each(function() {
   var len = $(this).html().length;
   var speed = 100;
   var time = 4 + (4*len)/speed;
   $(this).attr('style', 'animation: marquee '+time+'s linear infinite;');
});
```

In the JSfiddle, you can play around with the formula until you get a speed you like.  Just change the JS code and click "Run" in top-left.

Answer (score 0):

if you change your html so that

```
<p class="marquee" id="mID">
```

you could then use javascript to manipulate the elements of your

```
document.getElementById("mID").style.WebkitTransitionDuration = "1s"; // Code for Safari 3.1 to 6.0
document.getElementById("mID").style.transitionDuration = "1s";
```